# Set callerID using Asterisk CLI channel originate command

Tags: asterisk, sip

I am trying to automate calls in Asterisk. For its first step, i am trying to make a call via Asterisk CLI. Then I will automate via bash script. I want to set callerID and make a call via SIP Trunk. I can make a call with following command. How can i set callerID in this command.

```
channel originate SIP/commpeak/${callingNumber}
```

I tried the given command but it is not setting callerID however call is placed

```
channel originate SIP/commpeak/yyyyy  Application Set(CALLERID(number)=xxxx
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but it looks like your command is missing a closing parenthesis after 'xxxx'

Comment: ...or it has an opening parenthesis too much

Answer (score 0):

You can call via Local channels(call via dialplan, not sip) or use context,extension,priority as destination for command(second leg).

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Local+Channel